# python2.7 + pymongo: error: Use of SCRAM-SHA-256 requires undigested passwords

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, passwords, pymongo

Trying to revive an old python app. Python script is trying to connect to mongo.  Getting this error:

> **Use of SCRAM-SHA-256 requires undigested passwords**

Mac OSX 10.13.6
conda environment, all packages installed locally for the user.
python2.7 (can not upgrade)
pymongo 2.9.1

Other stuff installed with `pip2.7 install -r requirements`:

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Cors==2.1.2
Flask-PyMongo==0.3.1
```

in Mongo I created an admin user:
db.createUser({user:"admin", pwd:"abc123",roles:`[{role:"userAdminAnyDatabase",db:"admin"}], passwordDigestor:"server" })` and I can see it with `db.getUsers()`. Also tried with `mechanisms : [“SCRAM-SHA-256”]`, `mechanisms : [“SCRAM-SHA-1”]` and with both of them. Running my python script always gives this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "pymm_run.py", line 467, in
>   
>       args.func(args)   File "pymm_run.py", line 186, in bootstrap_restore
>       db = get_db()   File "/Users/myuser/matchminer-api/matchminer/database.py", line 50, in
>   get_db
>       connection[MONGO_DBNAME].add_user(MONGO_USERNAME, MONGO_PASSWORD)   File
>   "/Users/myuser/miniconda3/envs/matchminer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py",
>   line 966, in add_user
>       (not uinfo["users"]), name, password, read_only, **kwargs)   File "/Users/myuser/miniconda3/envs/matchminer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py",
>   line 892, in _create_or_update_user
>       read_preference=ReadPreference.PRIMARY, **opts)   File "/Users/myuser/miniconda3/envs/matchminer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py",
>   line 535, in command
>       codec_options, **kwargs)[0]   File "/Users/myuser/miniconda3/envs/matchminer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py",
>   line 440, in _command
>       msg, allowable_errors)   File "/Users/myuser/miniconda3/envs/matchminer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py",
>   line 213, in _check_command_response
>       raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response) pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command SON([('createUser', 'user'),
>   ('pwd', u'fa26a506aa0f786a447bbd6d1caaa8b5'), ('digestPassword',
>   False), ('roles', ['dbOwner']), ('writeConcern', {})]) on namespace
>   matchminer.$cmd failed: Use of SCRAM-SHA-256 requires undigested
>   passwords

Why is this happening and what's the remedy?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check your pymongo version. As stated in the ansible module page:

Requires the pymongo Python package on the remote host, version 2.4.2+. This can be installed using pip or the OS package manager. @see http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/installation.html

I simply run pip -U install pymongo